# rails 3.2.9 + ember.js 1.0.0-pre.2 keeps giving template not found error, any clue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Is there a sample Rails backend + ember.js 1.0.0-pre.2 app to refer.
My application is broken after upgrade.

I read about the named handlebars but there seems to be an issue.

If I write in index.html.haml

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>HI</h1>
</script>
```

Ember.TEMPLATES has a template named application

if I write a file application.handlebars with same content, I get the error Unable to find template 'application'

Is there any path configuration which has to be done which is missing. Please help.

Comment: :-) Just upgraded my gems and got stuck.

Comment: check http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2012-11-22-introducing-the-rails-api-project not sure of related ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm maintaining an up-to-date Rails / ember example you could reference:

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example

Are you using ember-rails to compile your templates? Of course, you'll also need to require your templates in your `application.js` if you're using the asset pipeline.

Comment: i have that set, i just upgraded the gems. I am already referring your code, thanks for maintaining that. no clue whats breaking my code.

Comment: Actually Ember.TEMPLATES is not having anything in it but I can see HandlebarsTemplates is listing all the templates. I even tried configuring the template path. Is there any where else you suggest I must look into ?

Comment: difference lies in precompile:                                                          Your code has the template included as  Ember.TEMPLATES["app/templates/contact"] = Ember.Handlebars.template( ... )                                                                                              While mine looks like:                                                    (function() {
            this.HandlebarsTemplates || (this.HandlebarsTemplates = {});
            this.HandlebarsTemplates["app/templates/application"] =

Comment: Sounds like your templates aren't being compiled with ember-rails, but with a straight handlebars pre-compiler. Ember requires templates to be in the Ember namespace.

Comment: thanks for help problem was happening as I was having the gem handlebars-assets which was compiling the handlebars files. I removed the handlebars-assets and it worked. This used to work in 1.0.pre Any how now its working, it was my bad to add the handlebars-assets.

Comment: Was it the same for 1.0.pre if you are aware of ?

Comment: Glad you tracked that down - I can see how the handlebars-assets gem could cause this conflict. Ember has required that templates be in the Ember namespace for as long as I can remember (even back to the 0.9.x releases).

Answer (score 0):

Removed handlebars-assets Gem from Gemfile it used to work till 1.0.pre, it was generating handlebars which were not compatible to Ember code. Ember adds all templates to Ember.TEMPLATES, it was adding into HandlebarsTemplates.

Actually handlebars-assets was never needed. Thanks everyone for help.